# Single thread 'gnu parallel'

Tags: bash, xargs, gnu-parallel

This might sound contradictory, but is there a way to run parallel in a simple "serial" fashion, without even loading a thread pool? I'm using parallel as a safer and more powerful/functional alternative to xargs.

The issue I'm facing is that inside an *already* parallel'ed piece of code, I'd like to sequentially process a bunch of args (the jobs are actually trivial, and my CPU is already running 100%).

I know about the "-P 1" option, but it would appear that even then, parallel will create a job pool (or something), and this actually has a fair amount of overhead. Example:

```
monarch:~/tests$ time ls -1 | xargs -n 1 -d $'\n' -I{} echo {} > /dev/null

real    0m1.084s
user    0m0.073s
sys     0m1.053s
monarch:~/tests$ time ls -1 | parallel -P1 'echo {} > /dev/null'

real    0m4.903s
user    0m2.235s
sys     0m3.046s
```

As you can see, parallel as an almost 400% overhead here. The example is trivial of course, but my real use case is actually not much more complicated than that, and I *do* leverage parallel's string replacement capabilities.

Any better way to do what I'm trying to do? I'd like to avoid for-loop/xargs, as I'd have to rewrite those string replacements...

(I'm using parallel in bash, for what it's worth)

Comment: Maybe someone can help you achieve the "string replacement capabilities" you need using simpler tools that run serially. You could update your question with the string replacement capabilities you seek...

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish? For parallelism, I'd be thinking 'why not use a script that supports parallel' - like perl.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, it got shipped incomplete. My current task might be XY, but I'd really like to just know the best way to use parallel as a drop in replacement for xargs.

Answer (score 1):

If GNU Parallel takes up 100% of a core, look at: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Speeding-up-fast-jobs

Also `--ungroup` will make it faster, if you do not care about the output.